# TikZ: extend a line along a path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to extend a line.  I could find the angle and then use `(\angle:\radius)` to do this.  I was wondering if there is a way to execute this command without having to do the math.

[image]

In the image, we have a concave lens with the focus labelled as `F`.  I want to draw lines that are on the same path from the focus to `(0, \y cm)` but I only want the section of the line that starts at `(0, \y cm)` and moves outwards from the paraxial rays.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lH}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lR}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sA}{asin(\lH/\lR)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\base}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xshi}{\base/2}

  \draw[yshift = -2cm, xshift = -\xshi cm] (0, \lH cm)
  arc[start angle = -\sA, delta angle = 2*\sA, radius = \lR cm] --
  +(\base cm, 0)
  arc[start angle = 180 - \sA, delta angle = 2*\sA, radius = \lR cm]
   -- cycle;

  \begin{scope}[decoration = {
      markings,
      mark = at position 0.1 with {\arrow{stealth}},
      mark = at position 0.75 with {\arrow{stealth}}
    }
    ]
    \foreach \y in {0.5, 0.25, 0, -0.25, -0.5}{
      \draw[postaction = decorate] (-1.5cm, \y cm) -- (0, \y cm) %extend lines along the path command here;
    }
  \end{scope}

  \fill[fill = black] (-1cm, 0) circle[radius = 0.015cm] node[below,
  font = \tiny] {$F$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you accept a clip to the lens path?  If not, the best I can think of would be to use intersections to compute the starting points of the rays.

Comment: @AndrewStacey you mean the ending points to the rays path, correct?  I thought about using the `intersections` library.  I want to keep the path in one argument inside the `foreach` command.  This way the arrows will be on the whole path without multiple scopes if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry could you please rephrase want you want, because my english is too poor.

Comment: @Tarass Imagine if we drew a line from the focus, `F`, to `(0, \y cm)`.  This line has some associated angle. I want to continue this line at this angle from the point `(0, \ycm)` outwards.  I don't actually want to draw the portion from the focus to the point.

Comment: If you want a single path then the `intersections` library is the way to go.

Comment: Plus the `calc` library to draw the extension since you can draw from the intersection in the direction of F for -1cm, or however long you want.

Comment: Where the red line has to begin, on the left side of the lens ? at the end of your black lines ? else ?

Comment: What `at this angle` means ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lH}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lR}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sA}{asin(\lH/\lR)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\base}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xshi}{\base/2}

  \draw[yshift = -2cm, xshift = -\xshi cm,name path=lens] (0, \lH cm)
  arc[start angle = -\sA, delta angle = 2*\sA, radius = \lR cm] --
  +(\base cm, 0)
  arc[start angle = 180 - \sA, delta angle = 2*\sA, radius = \lR cm]
   -- cycle;
  \fill[fill = black] (-1cm, 0) coordinate (F) circle[radius = 0.015cm] node[below,
  font = \tiny] {$F$}; 

  \begin{scope}[decoration = {
      markings,
      mark = at position 0.1 with {\arrow{stealth}},
      mark = at position 0.75 with {\arrow{stealth}}
    }
    ]
    \foreach \y  in {0.5, 0.25, 0, -0.25, -0.5}{
      \draw[postaction = decorate] (-1.5cm, \y cm) -- (0, \y cm)
      coordinate (A) 
      -- ($(F)!3!(A)$) ;      
      %extend lines along the path command here;
    }
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**From the edge of the lens (for fun and physicaly wrong) :**

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections,calc}

        %%%%                        ---- Use path several times
        %%%%                        ---- thanks to Andrew Stacey
        \makeatletter
        \tikzset{
          use path for main/.code={%
            \tikz@addmode{%
              \expandafter\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@#1\endcsname
            }%
          },
          use path for actions/.code={%
            \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@preactions\expandafter{\tikz@preactions\expandafter\let\expandafter\tikz@actions@path\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@#1\endcsname}%
          },
          use path/.style={%
            use path for main=#1,
            use path for actions=#1,
          }
        }

% #1 premier path               ---- Intersection ----
% #2 second path
% #3 nom des points
\newcommand{\InterSec}[3]{%
\path[name intersections={of=#1 and #2, by=#3, sort by=#1,total=\t}]
\pgfextra{\xdef\InterNb{\t}}; }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lH}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lR}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sA}{asin(\lH/\lR)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\base}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xshi}{\base/2}

  \draw[yshift = -2cm, xshift = -\xshi cm,name path=lens] (0, \lH cm)
  arc[start angle = -\sA, delta angle = 2*\sA, radius = \lR cm] --
  +(\base cm, 0)
  arc[start angle = 180 - \sA, delta angle = 2*\sA, radius = \lR cm]
   -- cycle;
  \fill[fill = black] (-1cm, 0) coordinate (F) circle[radius = 0.015cm] node[below,
  font = \tiny] {$F$}; 

  \begin{scope}[decoration = {
      markings,
      mark = at position 0.1 with {\arrow{stealth}},
      mark = at position 0.75 with {\arrow{stealth}}
    }
    ]
%   \foreach \y  in {0.5, 0.25, 0, -0.25, -0.5}{
%     \draw[postaction = decorate] (-1.5cm, \y cm) -- (0, \y cm)
%     coordinate (A) 
%     -- ($(F)!3!(A)$) ;      
      %extend lines along the path command here;

    \foreach \y  in {0.5, 0.25, 0, -0.25, -0.5}{
      \path[name path=ray] (-1.5cm, \y cm) -- (0, \y cm) ;
      \InterSec{ray}{lens}{A}
      \draw[postaction = decorate] (-1.5cm, \y cm) -- (A) -- ($(F)!3!(A)$) ;      

    }
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that the bend should be at the point where the incoming ray hits the *edge* of the lens, not at the (vertical) centre of the lens.

Comment: Or maybe not.  To be on the line from the focal point, we're treating the lens as a single object rather than as a composite of two edges and only interested in the path of the ray as it comes *out* of the lens.  So I agree with your picture.

Comment: I think so, but Dustin speak about `(0,ycm)` not about the left surface of the lens ...

Comment: And in the source he explicitly writes the point from witch he wants the extension.

Comment: The second image is wrong. http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/pplato2/h-flap/phys6_3.html

Comment: I agree, but it is to illustrate the powerfull trick (one of them) that Andrew made.

Comment: @dustin If you are using rays, they are all wrong including the link, due to quantum electrodynamics. They are all shortcuts for approximating the real deal.